# firebase recycle view is not showing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I'm trying to read a list form a fire base in a recycle viewer, but it's not showing it to me.

this `addfood.java` - it's the class which i will show the blog flow in it:

package com.example.median1.sora;

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuView;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.core.Context;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

public class addfood extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView mBlogList;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_addfood);


        mDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Blog");
      mBlogList=(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.blog_list);
      mBlogList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mBlogList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);




    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog1,BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter1=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog1, BlogViewHolder>(

                Blog1.class,
                R.layout.blog_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog1 model, int position) {
          viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDesc());
            }
        };

        mBlogList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter1);
    }

    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
           View mView;

        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title){

            TextView post_title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title1);
            post_title.setText(title);

        }
        public void setDesc(String desc){


            TextView post_desc=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc1);
            post_desc.setText(desc);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.action_add){

          Intent u=new Intent(addfood.this,potedfood.class);
         startActivity(u);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);



    }
}
```

this is `blog1.java` this is the:

```
package com.example.median1.sora;

/**
 * Created by median1 on 9/23/2017.
 */

public class Blog1 {

    private String title;
    private String desc;
    private String image;
    public Blog1(){



    }

    public Blog1(String title, String desc, String image) {
        this.title = title;
        this.desc = desc;
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }


}
```

`addfood.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.median1.sora.addfood">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/blog_list"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

blog_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/post_image1"
            android:src="@mipmap/add_btn"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"

            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/post_title1"
            android:hint="name"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/post_desc1"
            android:hint="price"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textSize="16dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i had this same issue but then i saw this solution it turns out the adapter needs to start listening and it has to be made global
To solve this, first make your adapter variable global:

```
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<UserInformation, EmployeeViewHolder> adapter;
```

Then you need to add the following lines of code in your onStart() and onStop() methods:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    adapter.startListening();
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(adapter != null) {
        adapter.stopListening();
    }
}
```

Because the adapter uses a listener to check for database changes, in order to make it work, you need to start listening first. And when you close the application, you need to stop listening.